# Laravel db insert still process when close browser

Tags: php, laravel-5

here is code in my insert route:

```
Route::get('addData',function(){

    $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
    $normalBegin = time();
    for($i = 0;$i<2000;$i++){
        \DB::insert('insert into dist(id,num) values(null,:num)',[':num'=>$faker->numberBetween(1,10000)]);
    }
});
```

And when i execute it 1 or 2 seconds, i closed my browser. But i found that data is increasing. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 3):

It's because the request is processed by the server. To stop it you would have to restart the apache server - browser can't do it